# why the time stamp of the message is later than the rosbag time?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm debugging my code with rosbag replay. In my code, I did tf transform like this:

```
tf.transformPose(target_frame, input_pose, output_pose);
```

Sometimes, there's an exception thrown, which read:

```
"Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1484037737.206813097 but the latest data is at time 1484037724.492085834, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]"
```

I checked in the debugger, and found the time stamp of the message input_pose is later than the rosbag time:

```
p input_pose.stamp_ 
$1  sec = 1484037737, nsec = 206813097
p ros::Time::now()
$2  sec = 1484037724, nsec = 918256570
```

Also, the rosbag play console shows:

```
 [PAUSED]   Bag Time: 1484037724.967132
```

The commands I used to run the rosbag is

```
rosbag play --clock --pause bagfile.bag
```

And the param use_sim_time is already set to true:

```
$rosparam get use_sim_time
true
```

Could anyone please help with this problem? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251781/why-the-time-stamp-of-the-message-is-later-than-the-rosbag-time?/) by [pitpet](https://answers.ros.org/users/24937/pitpet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-11**:
Is you data generated on the same computer that records the bag? if those happen on two different computers, it's possible that their clocks were out of sync.

**Comment by [pitpet](https://answers.ros.org/users/24937/pitpet/) on 2017-01-13**:
It turns out to be I'm restarting the rosbag play again but the debugging process is not restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out to be I'm restarting the rosbag play again but the debugging process is not restarted.

---

Originally posted by [pitpet](https://answers.ros.org/users/24937/pitpet/) with karma: 38 on 2017-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-13**:
@pitpet: please don't close questions when they are answered. It's better to just accept the answer in that case, as it's much more clear from the main question listing that the question was actually answered. You can accept an answer (even your own) by ticking the checkmark to the left of it.